# Aligning two equations, on the same line

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

I want to align two equations, one in the middle of the page and the other on the left hand side of the page.

```
$When\,\,t=1,\,C=10 \bigg)$ $$ \implies 10=Ae^{-t},$$
```

I would like it to be essentially on the same line, but the first statement is a little higher than the last part of the equation.

Comment: Could using a table be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @ebo , I'll have a look, whether that works.

Comment: Which equations?

Comment: Surely you don't what `When` or the `)` to be in math mode? Words should never be set in math italic.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , yeah, that is correct, how would format it so that 'when' is not in math mode?

Comment: Just move the `$` after the When, but it's hard to guess the intended meaning here why is there nothing to the left of the `\implies` ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean one of these? I use `flalign*` and the `eqparbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox} %

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
 &\eqparbox{Lbox}{When\,\,$ t=1,\,C=10 \bigg) $} & \implies 10 & =Ae^{-t}, &\hspace{\eqboxwidth{Lbox}}&
 \end{flalign*}
%
\begin{flalign*} & & & & & \\
\intertext{Without \texttt{eqparbox}:}
& \text{When}\,\, t=1,\,C=10 \bigg) & \implies 10 & =Ae^{-t}, & & %
\end{flalign*}
```

\end{document} 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A very simple (but not so elegant) way is to use `tabularx` environment.
You create a table with 3 columns of the same width and then put the text in the first two, left aligned and centered respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}XX}
When $t=1,\,C=10 \bigg)$ & $\implies 10=Ae^{-t},$ & 
\end{tabularx} 
\end{document}
```